# What is the Cyrillic font used in Andrey Zvyagintsev's movies?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What is the Cyrillic font used in Andrey Zvyagintsev's movies? Examples: Leviathan, 2014; Elena, 2011.

(I've tried searching on WhatTheFont, but there were no matches.)

[image: ПРЕДСТАВЛЯЮТ][image: ФИЛЬМ АНДРЕЯ ЗВЯГИНЦЕВА]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trajan Pro 3](https://typekit.com/fonts/trajan) from Adobe Typekit. Is the cyrillic alphabet of the classic roman Trajan font.

[image: trajan]